# Does any convergent sequence of unit vectors converge to a unit vector?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(V,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$ be a normed vector space and suppose $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence in $V$ that converges to $u$. If each term in $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ has **unit length**, can we conclude that $u$ **is** of unit length?

I would say it is true, because for all $u,w$ in $V$, we have
$$\lvert\Vert u\Vert-\Vert w\Vert\rvert\leq\Vert u+w\Vert\leq\Vert u\Vert+\Vert w\Vert,$$
and for each $n$, we have
$$\lvert\Vert u-u_n\Vert-1\rvert=\lvert\Vert u-u_n\Vert-\Vert u_n\Vert\rvert\leq\Vert u\Vert\leq\Vert u-u_n\Vert+\Vert u_n\Vert=\Vert u-u_n\Vert+1.$$
Applying the sandwich theorem leads to $\Vert u\Vert=1$. Am I right? Thank you.

Comment: perhaps an easier way: $\mid\mid \cdot \mid\mid: V \to \mathbb R$ is continuous...

Comment: @jacob Yeah, that's faster if one knows something about continuity. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily verify that $| \|x\| - \|y\| | \leq \|x-y\|$ by the triangle inequality.
Hence, if $(u_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of unit vectors converging to $u$, then, $| \|u\| - 1 | \leq \|u - u_n \|$ tends to zero as $n \to \infty$ i.e. $\|u\| = 1$.